# Show specific output through if else statement

Tags: javascript

I'm working out how to show entries in a dropdown list in dat.gui interface based on user input, but the issue I'm having is not related to the dat.gui programming, but rather my lack of javascript skill.

I've got two lists, one showing `Starsystem` and `0` and `1` as designations.
The other is `Planets` that show the specific planets inside `Starsystem`. 
How do I program this statement so these two arrays only show when 0 or 1 is selected?

```
var jumpSwitcher = 0;

    this.Starsystems = 'dat.gui';
//Starsystem list
    gui.add(this, 'Starsystems', ['0', '1']).onChange(function(value) {
        if (value === '1') {
            jumpSwitcher = 1;
        }
    });

    this.Planets = 'dat.gui';
//if the var jumpSwitcher is 0, display these variables in the Planets array.
    if (jumpSwitcher === 0) {
        Planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune'];
    } 

//if the jumpSwitcher is 1, meaning if the user has clicked on "1" under the Starsystem, show these planets. 
    else if (jumpSwitcher === 1) {
        Planets = ['Ilos', 'Tuchanka', 'Palaven', 'Illium'];
    }

    gui.add(this, 'Planets', Planets).name("Planets in this system").onChange(function(value) {
    });
```

I'd say that this should work, but somehow it doesn't. It does when I simply make the condition in the statement something like if (1>0) {show 1} else {show 2}.

PS:

```
var jumpSwitcher = 1;  
    this.Starsystems = 'dat.gui';
gui.add(this, 'Starsystems', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']).onChange(function(value) {

    jumpSwitcher = +value;

});

this.Planets = 'dat.gui';

switch (jumpSwitcher) {
    case 1:    
        gui.add(this, 'Planets', ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']).name("Planets in this system").onChange(function(value) {

        });    

        break;
    case 2:    
        gui.add(this, 'Planets', ['Ilos', 'Tuchanka', 'Illium', 'Palaven']).name("Planets in this system").onChange(function(value) {

        });

        break;    
}
```

Comment: use a else statement after else if statement. That will cover every condition other than 0 and 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `jumpSwitcher`

Change

```
if (value === '1') {
    jumpSwitcher = 1;
}
```

to

```
jumpSwitcher = +value;
```

This sets `jumpSwitcher` to a number of value.

Another solution could be the cange of the value inside of the array to ge a numerical value instead of a string, if these values are connected.

```
gui.add(this, 'Starsystems', [0, 1]).onChange(function(value) {
//                           ^^^^^^
    jumpSwitcher = value;
});
```